# iOS app crashed while opening and closing the WebView (WKWebView)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, wkwebview

I'm developing an iOS application using Xamarin.Forms and it contains WebView in it. Recently my iOS crashing while opening and closing the WebView. It works fine in my iPad (iOS 10.1.1) but crashing in my iPod (iOS 11.3).

Here is my app crash report,

```
Thread 4 name:  Finalizer
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   WebKit                          0x0000000192dd08e4 

WebKit::WebCookieManagerProxy::processPoolDestroyed+ 1747172 () + 448

1   WebKit                          0x0000000192dd0744 WebKit::WebCookieManagerProxy::processPoolDestroyed+ 1746756 () + 32
2   WebKit                          0x0000000192ee0530 WebKit::WebProcessPool::~WebProcessPool+ 2860336 () + 260
3   WebKit                          0x0000000192fa0cf0 -[WKProcessPool dealloc] + 36
4   WebKit                          0x0000000192c4069c API::PageConfiguration::~PageConfiguration+ 108188 () + 212
5   WebKit                          0x0000000192f88e34 -[WKObject dealloc] + 36
6   WebKit                          0x0000000192e66018 WebKit::WebPageProxy::~WebPageProxy+ 2359320 () + 1932
7   WebKit                          0x0000000192f88e34 -[WKObject dealloc] + 36
8   WebKit                          0x0000000192c3c778 API::FrameInfo::~FrameInfo+ 92024 () + 48
9   WebKit                          0x0000000192f81c68 -[WKFrameInfo dealloc] + 36
10  WebKit                          0x0000000192d830bc API::NavigationAction::~NavigationAction+ 1429692 () + 168
11  WebKit                          0x0000000192f87268 -[WKNavigationAction dealloc] + 36
12  WebKit                          0x0000000192cb82d0 WTF::BlockPtr<void (WKNavigationActionPolicy)> WTF::BlockPtr<void 
WKNavigationActionPolicy)>::fromCallable<WebKit::NavigationState::NavigationClient::decidePolicyForNavigationAction(WebKit::WebPageProxy&, WTF::Ref<API::NavigationAction, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<API::NavigationAction> >&&, WTF::Ref<WebKit::WebFramePolicyListenerProxy, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WebKit::WebFramePolicyListenerProxy> >&&, API::Object*)::$_2>(WebKit::NavigationState::NavigationClient::decidePolicyForNavigationAction(WebKit::WebPageProxy&, WTF::Ref<API::NavigationAction, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<API::NavigationAction> >&&, WTF::Ref<WebKit::WebFramePolicyListenerProxy, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WebKit::WebFramePolicyListenerProxy> >&&, API::Object*)::$_2)::'lambda'(void const*)::__invoke+ 598736 (void const*) + 88
13  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x0000000182c98a5c _Block_release + 152
14  MobileAppiOS    0x00000001018583dc 0x10056c000 + 19842012
15  MobileAppiOS    0x00000001018577c4 0x10056c000 + 19838916
16  MobileAppiOS    0x00000001018cfcbc 0x10056c000 + 20331708
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f2d220 _pthread_body + 272
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f2d110 _pthread_body + 0
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f2bb10 thread_start + 4
```

Does anyone have idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

It seem its Xamarin bug: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4130, already fixed, wait for release